# i want to integrate a sms api on my laravel application

Tags: php, laravel-5, infobip, infobip-api

**my controller**

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;

class MessageController extends Controller
{
    public function manyMessage(Request $request){

        $message = $request->input("message");
        $mobile = $request->input("mobile");
        $encodeMessage = urlencode($message);
        $authKey = 'authKey';
        $senderId = 'senderId';
        $route = 4;
        $postData = $request->all();
        $mobileNumber = implode('',$postData['mobile']);
        $arr = str_split($mobileNumber,11);
        $mobiles = implode(",",$arr);
        $data = array(
            'authKey' => $authKey,
            'mobiles' => $mobiles,
            'message' => $encodeMessage,
            'sender' => $senderId,
            'route' => $route,

        );
        $url = "https://api.infobip.com";

        $ch = curl_init();
        curl_setopt_array($ch, array(
           CURLOPT_URL => $url,
           CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER =>true,
           CURLOPT_POST => true,
           CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => $postData,
        ));

       curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST,0);
       curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER,0);

       $output = curl_exec($ch);

       if(curl_errno($ch)){

           echo 'error :'. curl_error($ch);

       }

       curl_close($ch);
        Session::flash('success', 'Message sent Successfully!');
       return redirect("/records");
    }
}
```

**view**

```
<form role="form" action="{{url("/sendMessage")}}" method="post">
                                {{csrf_field()}}
                                <textarea type="hidden" class="form-control" row="4">Write Text</textarea><br>
                                <input type="submit" class="pull-left btn btn-primary btn-small" value="Send"/><br /><br />

                                <input type="checkbox" id="select_all" name="select_all"/> Select All<br/><br />
                                <div class="row">
                                    <div class="col-lg-12">
                                        <div class="panel panel-default">
                                            <div class="panel-heading">
                                                New Converts / First Timer
                                            </div>
                                            <!-- /.panel-heading -->
                                            <div class="panel-body">
                                                <div class="dataTable_wrapper">
                                                    <table class="table table-striped table-bordered table-hover" id="dataTables-example">
                                                        <thead>
                                                        <tr>
                                                            <th></th>
                                                            <th>Name</th>
                                                            <th>Phone Number</th>
                                                            <th>Home Address</th>
                                                            <th>Email Address</th>
                                                            <th>Date</th>
                                                            <th>Action</th>
                                                        </tr>
                                                        </thead>
                                                        <tbody>
                                                        @if(isset($record))
                                                            @foreach($record as $record)

                                                                <tr class="odd gradeX">
                                                                    <td><input type="checkbox" class="checkbox" name="mobile[]" value="{{$record->phone}}"></td>
                                                                    <td>{{$record->first_name}} - {{$record->last_name}}</td>
                                                                    <td>{{$record->phone}}</td>
                                                                    <td>{{$record->home_address}}</td>
                                                                    <td>{{$record->email}}</td>
                                                                    <td>{{ Carbon\Carbon::parse($record->created_at)->format('d-m-Y H:i:s') }}</td>
                                                                    <td><div class="">
                                                                            <a href="{{URL::to('/editNewConvert')}}/{{$record->id}}" class="btn btn-primary btn-xs">Edit</a>
                                                                            <a href="{{URL::to('/deleteNewConvert')}}/{{$record->id}}" class="btn btn-danger btn-xs">Delete</a>
                                                                        </div></td>
                                                                </tr>
                                                            @endforeach
                                                        @endif
                                                        </tbody>
                                                    </table>
                                                </div>
</form>
```

**Error**

> (1/1) ErrorException Array to string conversion in
>   MessageController.php (line 37) at HandleExceptions->handleError(8,
>   'Array to string conversion',
>   'C:\xampp\htdocs\blog\app\Http\Controllers\MessageController.php',
>   37, array('request' => object(Request), 'message' => null, 'mobile' =>
>   array('08028479963'), 'encodeMessage' => '', 'authKey' => 'authKey',
>   'senderId' => 'senderId', 'route' => 4, 'postData' => array('_token'
>   => 'p7Cg8f0nQzCjwuuVz83WmQngvp7zeiGnQRQS8FPi', 'dataTables-example_length' => '10', 'mobile' => 'Array'),
>   'mobileNumber' => '08028479963', 'arr' => array('08028479963'),
>   'mobiles' => '08028479963', 'data' => array('authKey' => 'authKey',
>   'mobiles' => '08028479963', 'message' => '', 'sender' => 'senderId',
>   'route' => 4), 'url' => 'https://api.infobip.com', 'ch' => resource))
>   at curl_setopt_array(re

Comment: Please reformat your question so we can read it

Comment: Please format view code

Answer (score 1):

You have created parameters array of **$data** and trying to send **$postData** as post field, Please **change $postData to $data** and try again

Change CURL code as below:

```
    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt_array($ch, array(
       CURLOPT_URL => $url,
       CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER =>true,
       CURLOPT_POST => true,
       CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => $postData,
    ));

   curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST,0);
   curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER,0);

   $output = curl_exec($ch);

   if(curl_errno($ch)){
       echo 'error :'. curl_error($ch);
   }
   curl_close($ch);
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the [Laravel SMS API plugin](https://packagist.org/packages/gr8shivam/laravel-sms-api), just add 2-3 config parameters as per your SMS service and you're done. Everything else is handled by the plugin.